# Getting multiple Mono objects with reactive Mongo queries

Tags: spring, mongodb, mono, spring-webflux, reactive

I'm using the webflux framework for spring boot, the behavior I'm trying to implement is creating a new customer in the database, if it does not already exist (throw an exception if it does)
and also maintain another country code database (if the new customer is from a new country, add to the database, if the country is already saved, use the old information)

This is the function in the service :

```
    public Mono<Customer> createNewCustomer(Customer customer) {
    if(!customer.isValid()) {
        return Mono.error(new BadRequestException("Bad email or birthdate format"));
    }
    
    Mono<Customer> customerFromDB = customerDB.findByEmail(customer.getEmail());
    
    Mono<Country> countryFromDB = countryDB.findByCountryCode(customer.getCountryCode());

    Mono<Customer> c = customerFromDB.zipWith(countryFromDB).doOnSuccess(new Consumer<Tuple2<Customer, Country>>() {

        @Override
        public void accept(Tuple2<Customer, Country> t) {
            System.err.println("tuple " + t);
            if(t == null) {
                countryDB.save(new Country(customer.getCountryCode(), customer.getCountryName())).subscribe();
                customerDB.save(customer).subscribe();
                return;
            }
            Customer cus = t.getT1();
            Country country = t.getT2();
            if(cus != null) {
                throw new CustomerAlreadyExistsException();
            }
            if(country == null) {
                countryDB.save(new Country(customer.getCountryCode(), customer.getCountryName())).subscribe();
            }
            else {
                customer.setCountryName(country.getCountryName());
            }
        
            customerDB.save(customer).subscribe();
            
        }
    }).thenReturn(customer);
    return c;
}
```

My problem is, the tuple returns null if either country or customer are not found, while I need to know about them separately if they exist or not, so that I can save to the database correctly.
`country == null` is never true
I also tried to use `customerFromDB.block()` to get the actual value but I receive an error that it's not supported, so I guess that's not the way

Is there anyway to do two queries to get their values?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the following solution:

```
public Mono<Customer> createNewCustomer(Customer customer) {
    if(!customer.isValid()) {
        return Mono.error(new BadRequestException("Bad email or birthdate format"));
    }
    
     return customerDB.findByEmail(customer.getEmail())
             .defaultIfEmpty(new Customer("empty", "", "", "", "", ""))
             .flatMap(cu -> {
                if(!cu.getEmail().equals("empty")) {
                    return Mono.error(new CustomerAlreadyExistsException());
                }
                
                return countryDB.findByCountryCode(customer.getCountryCode())
                        .defaultIfEmpty(new Country(customer.getCountryCode(), customer.getCountryName()))
                        .flatMap(country -> {
                            customer.setCountryName(country.getCountryName());
                            customerDB.save(customer).subscribe();
                            countryDB.save(country).subscribe();
                            return Mono.just(customer);});
                
            });
}
```

Instead of doing both queries simulatneaously, I queried for one result and then queries for the next, I think this is the reactive way of doing it, but I'm open for corrections.